# Instagram API - Media returned is cut off

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, endpoint

I've searched everywhere but there is not one link explaining or giving a fix as to why this happens.

Whenever I make an endpoint request to Instagram for pictures, most of the image url's given are cut off - not the whole photo is there when compared to the original post on Instagram. It seems to me, and perhaps logically, that the images which are cut off are one's which are not exactly square.

Is there any way to get the full image, without the cropping to fit it in an exact square?

Thank you.

EDIT: Just realised there is a non-square media option in the developers console, however I have this checked but it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Although this does work, disappointing Instagram's non-square media feature doesn't do what it's meant to.

```
$image_url = $insta_liked_array['data'][$image_key]['images']
['standard_resolution']['url'];

//parse url to get last segment before image name

$segments = explode('/', parse_url($image_url, PHP_URL_PATH));
$segment_removal = $segments[5];

//New Url without the segment
$image_url_dynamic = str_replace("/" . $segment_removal,"",$image_url);

echo $image_url_dynamic;
```

Edit:
Sometimes the above might not perform as expected, I have gone through the trouble of making something which will...26 lines of code all because instagram can't fix a simple checkbox!

```
//'/e35/c' is a common string in each url, so from this we can take 
//away the /c... section using this info
//whatever index [e35] is, check if the next index has c as the first 
//letter, if so, remove that part

echo "Exploding url, checking for non-square media...\n\n";
$segments = explode('/', parse_url($image_url, PHP_URL_PATH));

if(in_array('e35', $segments)){
//get the index of e35
$e35_index = array_search('e35', $segments);
//if the letter 'c' is in the next seg, remove it
// to check if 'c' is in the next segment
$c_segment = $segments[$e35_index + 1];

if (strpos($c_segment, 'c') !== false) {
echo "Non square media resolve in progress...\n\n";
//get rid of that section +backslash, (replace with nothing)
$image_url = str_replace("/" . $c_segment,"",$image_url);
echo "New url has been made...\n\n\n\n" . $image_url;
}
elseif(strpos($c_segment, 'c') === false){
echo "Square media detected, no need to remove a segment...\n\n";
$image_url = $image_url;
}
else {
echo "An error occured";
}
}
else{
echo "An error occured - url should contain 'e35' string";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in your client configuration page of API to set the API to return non-square media, its in the migration tab:

[image]

Comment: This is what i had already pointed out as not working - it still only returns croppud square media. I have solved the problem now

Comment: @LucaSarif Make sure to recreate your access tokens after you change that setting; it doesn't apply to tokens already created.

Comment: Did do so many times, even created new clients from the start with this option ticked. I came to the conclusion that i must approve my app, which'll never happen, or it is just broken. @Steven Schobert